# ASP.Net is too slow

Tags: asp.net

Name: `http://localhost:50692/bfea4cb4df42428dac17db20239d7d53/arterySignalR/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAY8r9H53SS0mPVZi%2BJaxhmgAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAACxV1Yze0hqYW74IbMt%2F3ccAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAANgm3EjRWVa2PG4Y0yKe170oAAAA3HRUEcQdeyzIzSRY1%2B88s1AWq3zAs3dVYKoE8nrk0XpbjrLFXenhzRQAAACtcSj%2FmTPLei2BFkjrPAqbbTphxA%3D%3D&messageId=d-90D2E0DD-B%2C0%7CC%2C9%7CD%2C0&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53648%2F&browserName=Chrome&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F43.0.2357.132+Safari%2F537.36&tid=8&_=1436780235916`

Status: `200`

Type: `xhr`

Initiator: `browserLink:37`

Size: `336 B`

Time: `6.0 seconds`

From the `Network` tab in `Inspect Element` in Chrome.

It just does this over and over again without getting anywhere. I have no idea what parts of my code to give you, and I'd rather not swarm you with the whole project. Tell me what you need to see and I'll give you it.

When I click "copy as HAR" I get this: http://pastebin.com/tqqNGYpW

It's interesting that the 'log' at the top shows version 1.2, and I just uninstalled log4net version 1.2 and installed log4net version 2.x instead to fix another problem. The problem was related to some 32-bit 64-bit problems between LinqToExcel (it uses log4net).

This is almost certainly LinqToExcel-related. It only hangs sometimes. It continues doing the above even after I've stopped the loading process.

Further info:

The page that hangs displays Excel files from LinqToExcel. The page that does not use LinqToExcel does not hang. It doesn't matter if the page has Excel files to display, or not.

The hang occurs when I call the `Index()` method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using steer.Models;
using LinqToExcel;

namespace steer.Controllers
{
    public class FilesController : Controller
    {
        private UpFile.UpFileDBContext db = new UpFile.UpFileDBContext();

        // GET: Upload
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.UpFiles.ToList());
        }


        // GET: Upload/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            UpFile upFile = db.UpFiles.Find(id);
            if (upFile == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Uploaded\\"+upFile.Name);
            var firstSheet = excel.GetWorksheetNames().First();
            var excelRows = from c in excel.Worksheet(firstSheet)
                             select c;
            ViewBag.excelRows = excelRows;
            ViewBag.excelColumns = excel.GetColumnNames(firstSheet); ;
            ViewBag.numberOfColumns = ViewBag.excelColumns.Count;
            return View(upFile);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using SignalR?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: The pastebin file suggests so.

Comment: "Initiator: Browserlink" - this is a tool that allows communication between Visual Studio and the browser. This uses SignalR (and apparently "long polling") to communicate. I think you can ignore this - your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Some plugins I use might use it, I at least don't remember using it myself. Do you think that might be the cause?

Comment: Added further info. Sorry for the clutter.

Comment: Also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I'm assuming you have files you've uploaded in a database table and the page that is slow is the index which just shows the list of files.

If you have all the file details and the file contents in the same table then I suspect you're loading all those file contents for every single file every time you do an index.

Assuming this is the case you can either tell the linq to just select the info you want, or split out the data across 2 tables to make it so that you only end up with the data if you explicitly link it in.